# Outlook 2007 account settings reverting Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2007, autodiscovery

We just migrated from Exchange 2008 to Exchange 2013.  We still use Outlook 2007 at this time.  On our Windows 7 machines I am having trouble with users staying connected.  Several users are showing "Disconnected" in the lower corner of Outlook and are repeatedly prompted for a password.

My laptop was not having this issue, so I simply copied my settings to their Account Settings in mail under control panel.  The specific offender here was under more settings on the security tab. Here the users with the issue have "**Logon network security**" set to "**Anonymous**".  I change it to "**Negotiate Authentication**" and ensure the "**Encrypt data between Microsoft Office Outlook and Microsoft Exchange**" is checked.  This will fix their issue.

*However*, after a while (whether they close and reopen outlook or not I am unsure) the settings seem to revert back to what they were to begin with.  What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

We have quite the same situation, except that we use a hosted Exchange 2013 Server as a service. After asking our provider how to solve this behaviour, we got the answer that this is known to Microsoft and they are working on a solution.

It occurs only with Outlook 2007 and Exchange 2013.

The solution would be to migrate to Outlook 2010/2013. Or to wait until Microsoft has a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of searching we arrived at this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956531

On some machines I could get away with simply applying the fix explained in the article above.  We used a value of 1 for the DWORD UseWindowsUserCredentials.  On other machines I removed the users local email files, created a new Mail profile in control panel Mail(32), and manually reentered the email server information.